# replace current record on awk add space

Tags: awk

I would like to manipulate string with awk.

Now to see current record on awk i'm using `$0` and this works fine:

```
echo "foobar" | awk -v FS="" '{print $0 }'
```

my output is

```
foobar
```

Now I would like to replace my second character with 5th character:

```
echo "foobar" | awk -v FS="" '{$2=$5; print $0 }'
```

It works, but it adds space after each character:

```
f a o b a r
```

So my question is why awk add space after each character and how to so it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set OFS(Output field separator) to empty:

```
$ echo "foobar" | awk -v FS="" '{$2=$5; print $0 }' OFS=""
faobar
```

Comment: Why set FS at the front but OFS at the back of the script? `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=""} {$2=$5}1'`